# Optimize mysql Blob on slow connection

Tags: mysql, optimization, server-configuration

I'm using mysql 5.5. My OS is Centos7. I have this simple structure

```
Create table myContent
(
TheId int PK
Content blob
);
```

The size of each blob is around 100KB. I need to optimize

```
select * from myContent limit N.
```

Usually, I put N as 50 so it is about 5MB. It runs around 1 minute to retrieve. My internet speed is 10mbps.

The query was just fine until this corona pandemic happens and my internet provider slows the internet down a lot. I then subscribed to faster speed to 20mbps and my query is still super slow (Limiting 5 rows (500KB) takes more than 1 minute). I can't change to another internet provider because it is the only provider I have in my area.

I checked my MySQL traffic and actually the traffic is slower than usual. There is no table lock as well. Are there any other things that I can do to MySQL?

**EDIT:**
I think my explanation is not clear what my purpose is or what I'm trying to do. I tried to simply things so it won't get too complicated. I'm trying to create syncronization data between multiple local server using queue. All servers are located in different area and most of them is using the same internet provider. My blob is the result of compressed raw data. The blob is generated from each server that needs to be downloaded by another server. So here is my primary structure:

```
create table myQueue
(
    myQueueId int NOT NULL, -- PK
    serverId int DEFAULT NULL, -- this is the ID where the data is from
    blobId int DEFAULT NULL, -- the id of my blob table (TheId)
    timeupdate datetime, -- current time
    PRIMARY KEY (myQueueId),
    UNIQUE INDEX blobId (blobId),
    INDEX timeupdate(timeupdate)
);

CREATE TABLE downloadedServer (
    myQueueId int NOT NULL, -- PK
    serverId int(11) NOT NULL, -- PK
    serverIdDownloaded int(11) NOT NULL, -- PK
    PRIMARY KEY (myQueueId, serverId, serverIdDownloaded)
);

CREATE TABLE myContent
(
    TheId int NOT NULL, -- PK
    Content blob, -- this is the result of compressed data that is generated from the app that needs to be downloaded by another server. I tried my best so this is the very least amount of size that I can do
    PRIMARY KEY (TheId)
);
```

Everyday, the myQueue table is cleaned so it won't get bloated. My regular query in each server is as follows:

```
-- Check if there is any data that has to be downloaded
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myQueue q
 WHERE q.serverId != vServerId -- make sure it's not from the same server
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM downloadedServer d WHERE
   d.serverIdDownloaded = vServerId AND
   d.myQueueId = q.myQueueId AND
   d.serverId = q.serverId);

-- Then I download the content that has to be downloaded using this query.
-- This query gets very slow even I reduced the limit N since my internet provider slows the internet down. The server that subscribed different provider doesn't have this problem.
SELECT q.myQueueId, q.serverId, c.Content 
 FROM myQueue q 
  JOIN myContent c ON q.BlobId=c.TheId
   WHERE q.serverId != vServerId -- make sure it's not from the same server
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM downloadedServer d WHERE
     d.serverIdDownloaded = vServerId AND
     d.myQueueId = q.myQueueId AND
     d.serverId = q.serverId)
    ORDER BY q.timeupdate LIMIT N;
```

After it is downloaded, the blob is decompressed from the server which just downloaded. It happens every 15 minutes.

My query select * from myContent limit 5 is for testing purpose why downloading 500KB data takes a long time and I'm wondering how I can make it faster in such a slow connection.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: But if I don't limit my data, the size is much bigger since it is a blob

Comment: So, add an ORDER BY clause

Comment: While I'd check your premise that it's the connection (e.g. download a file from the server to see if it's just mysql, or let someone else test it to see if it's your hoster or home connection), if you have slow internet and need to download that data, there is not much we can do for you. I'd check if you actually need this data though. For developing, you may e.g. replace your data by 1kb dummy blobs. Also, usually you'd have a service(php, ...) on your server that accesses mysql locally, and clients connect to that service. So maybe you can evaluate the blobs on the server without download.

Comment: @Solarflare well, i did asked someone from another area with different internet provider to test the query and he said it runs pretty fast even he limit the query by 50 (around 5MB). I was wondering if I can tweak the server setting though.

Comment: @Strawberry i tried the order by clause and it has the same result

Comment: If your provider limits your download speed (and it seems established after the test with your friend), tweaking the mysql server doesn't really seem to be the right angle. You need to reduce the amount of data you need to download. Evaluate your data on the server by having a service tier/your application/... run on the server (which you should really consider anyway!); zip your blob (and store those in your database) and unzip them in your client; replace your data with dummy data. We don't really know what you do/why you transfer your data/how you can redesign your application though.

Comment: Strawberrys comment was not meant as a suggestion to improve speed, but to make your query sensible. Your query currently could give you by definition *any n random rows* if you do not specify an order. Only when you do, MySQL *has to* give you the first n rows defined by that order, so you should always specify an order, even if it looks like your query will automatically order by the pk. MySQL does not have to do that.

Comment: What could any human do with 5MB of blob data?  In a reasonable length of time?  Data selection to always retrieve the least rows of data will always be the winner.  SELECT *   is generally a bad idea for any table query.  Ask for least columns required to get the process completed.

Comment: The point of the `ORDER BY` is that _which_ 5 blobs you get is unpredictable.  That is it is a design point, not a performance issue.

Comment: What do you do with the blobs?  I ask because, if you can consume them on the server, you avoid the slow download.

Comment: Zipping is useless if it is any of most types of images.  They won't compress more than maybe 1%.  Text, on the other hand, compresses by a factor of 3.

Comment: Do a `traceroute` or `tracert` (depending on OS) so see what kind of hopping it does and what the latency is.  Also, use any of several internet speed tests (search for "speed test").  It would be interesting to see what speed they find.

Comment: Thanks guy for the comment. I edit my question and add more clarity. I hope it's clearer now.
@RickJames I did tracert and the result is 28 hops. I often got RTO and ping result is actually not bad. It is 380ms per 60bytes data.  And yes some of them are images. I did my best on the compression already and I thought it was "good enough" until now.

Comment: thanks @Solarflare. I actually already compress my data and the blob is the result. Yeah I think my query wasn't clear what I'm trying to do. I made revision to my question. Hope it is clear now

Comment: I still think you are looking for a mysql configuration that makes your connection faster, while it is doubtful that this is the cause. You need to investigate your connection problems! E.g. limiting traffic within the same network, while upload to your friends external network is fast would be an unusual way of throttling. 360ms ping inside the same provider network seems high. Do you use VPN? Is your server hacked and using your traffic? Does other traffic (files between your servers, internet speed tests, ...) work and/or fit to your assumption that your provider is throttling?

Comment: Ping time is 360 ms??  Reminds me of a gag.  A dozen people are eating a meal around a large table.  One asks to the salt (or soy sauce or whatever) passed.  So the guy passes it the long way around the table.  360 is as if it is going around the long way around the globe!

Comment: Hmmm...  Could there be a censor between you and your destination?  And it takes them time to check your image for naughty content?

Comment: I got it solved thanks to @Solarflare asked me if I'm using VPN. I didn't use VPN and I consider using it to make sure my provider is throttling. After using VPN, it just goes fast like before. Ping also became 200ms!